# Issue with wagmi sendTransaction hook in react native expo

Tags: react-native, next.js13, metamask, decentralized-applications, wagmi

`I have used the same hook sendTransction in both nextjs for web and expo for mobile app from wagmi, when i send transaction from web it perfectly opens up my metamask and approval popup appears but when i use send the same transaction from expo mobile app it opens up metamask but approval popup doesnt't come up

wagmi:1.4.3 in react native
wagmi:2.5.7 in nextjs

````
 const { config } = usePrepareSendTransaction({
    account: address,
    to: details?.to,
    value: String(details?.value),
    data: details?.data,
    gasPrice: details?.gasPrice,
    gas: String(details?.gas),
  });
const { sendTransaction, data: txData } = useSendTransaction(config);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (details != "") {
      setTimeout(() => {
        sendTransaction({
          account: address,
          to: details?.to,
          data: details?.data,
          value: String(details?.value),
          gas: String(details?.gas),
          gasPrice: details.gasPrice,
        });
      }, 3000);
    }
  }, [details]);    ```
`
This is what i m trying in mobile app`
````